# What needs to be modified to get desired result in this C code

Tags: c

I have written a small piece of code that would perform Run length encoding kind of stuff on 1-D array but still far from desired result.

```
main()
{
    int a[8]={2,0,0,0,3,0,0,9};
    int i,temp,ct=0,flag,m;
    int found[90]={0};
    for(i=0;i<=7;i++)
    {
        if(!a[i])
        {
            ct++;
            if(!found[a[i]])
            {
                flag=i;
                found[a[i]]=1;
            } 
        } 
    }

    a[flag]=ct;
    m=ct;    
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }       
}/* end of main*/
```

Now for above array i would like to have output something  below

```
 2 5 0 3 9
```

But with my piece of code am getting

```
 2 5 0 0 3
```

Can I have any suggestion on that?

Comment: 121 questions on SO so far and you *still* haven't learned to format your code ?

Comment: Please let me know how can i format my code

Comment: Just insert 4 spaces before each line. You can do this in NotePad++ by pasting the code and selecting all, hit tab, then copy paste into SO

Comment: See above - @dsolimano has done it for you now - please try and work on getting your code formatting right for future questions - people are more likely to answer your questions if they can read your code without too much difficulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't run length encoding turn 2,0,0,0,3,0,0,9 into 2 1 0 3 3 1 2 0 9 1?

1) The first thing I see is wrong is that you aren't looking at the entire array. You're using < to stop before 8, but also stopping at 7, so you only evaluate array items 0 - 6.

2) If ct stands for count it's never reset (ct=0 only on declaration). Also it's assignment is this: a[flag]= ct; which overwrites your original data. It basically tracks the value of i.

This is my version I've just put together:

```
#define SZ 8

main()
{
    int a[SZ]={2,0,0,0,3,0,0,9};
    int i; //absolute position

    int runningCount = 1; //because we start at array index 1 and not zero

    for (i = 1; i <= SZ; i++) {
        if (a[i - 1] == a[i]) //value same as one before it...
           runningCount++;
        else { // new value found. print last one, and the count of the last one.
            printf("%d %d ", a[i - 1], runningCount);
            runningCount = 1; //reset for next loop
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is `2 1 0 3 3 1 0 2 9 1`

Ok based on the comment left below, your algorithm would actually look like this:

```
#define SZ 8

main()
{
    int a[SZ]={2,0,0,0,3,0,0,9};
    int i; //absolute position

    int zero_count = 0; //target zeros specifically...

    for (i = 0; i < SZ; i++) {
        if (a[i] == 0)
           zero_count++;
    }

    //now write it out in a bizarre, unparsable format again...

    for (i = 0; i < SZ; i++) {

        if (a[i] != 0)           //write out all non zero values
            printf("%d ", a[i]);

        if (i == 0) { //this says put the zero count after the first number was printed
           printf("%d 0 ", zero_count); //inserting it into a strange place in the array
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs: `2 5 0 3 9`

Comment: Its not exactly Run Length encoding but I am trying to put number of 0's at one place

Comment: Can you elaborate please, then on how you arrive at your desired answer of  2 5 0 3 9 because I'm not sure how to get there?

Comment: This 2 5 0 3 9 what is desired .If we see the original array 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 9 ,it has five(5) occurring of 0's and that what need to place at one place like 2 5 0 3 9 and also need to remove extra 0's, only one 0 should be there to tell this element is occurred in repetition

Comment: Ok I understand now. You have 2 3 and 9 directly from the array and 5 and 0 denoting the total number of 0's found. Then a zero itself. Do you understand that the zeros appear either side of the 3 and you aren't saying how many (1,2,3,4) are on each side, so you would, using 2 5 0 3 9 ever be able to get back to the original array?

Comment: Getting back to original array is not my concerned just wanted to perform it in one way..

Comment: Thanks @Philluminati for your help .But still algoritham requires some changes to desired result .But anywat appreciate your efforts you put in here.

Answer (score 0):

You need a <= in your for loop:

```
for(i=0;i<=7;i++)
```

instead of

```
for(i=0;i< 7;i++)
```

Otherwise you miss the last element.

Comment: This is true, but actually doesn't even change the result.  There are larger issues here.

Answer (score 0):

All you appear to be doing is (a) counting the number of times 0 occurs in the array, and (b) replacing the first occurrence of 0 with that count.  It's not clear how this is meant to be a useful encoding.

In any case, you're not getting your desired result, at least in part, because you're only modifying one element of the array.  I suspect what you want, or at least think you want, is to shift the non-zero elements of the array to the left as you encounter them.

What is the utility of compressing the array in the way you propose?  Is some other piece of code going to have to reconstruct the original, and if so how do you expect to do so from your desired result?

Comment: To be honest I don't know the use of this encoding Scheme ,Its simply being asked in an Interview .And original version of this question carrying this encoding stuff on 2-D array.